# How can i define the vector to variable scalar?

Tags: matlab

I have A,B,C,D,E values all in size 1x1155. 
A=[1.0001, 1.0005, 1.00010,...,1.0009]. similar to B, C, D and E.
I need (A(1)+B(1))/(C(1)+D(1)E(1)) + (A(2)+B(2))/(C(2)+D(2)E(2)) + ... + (A(1155)+B(1155))/(C(1155)+D(1155)E(1155)). Therefore i need each individual variable using loop rather than defining one by one from 1 to 1155. Is there a way to do that in Matlab?

Comment: Look the example of this:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimproblem.html
The objective of the example is x(1) + x(2). It is easy to type manually.
But I have 1155 variable [meaning x(1)+x(2)+...+x(1155)] to optimise and it will take ages to type manually. Thus I must use loop.
My main part is to solve optivar('x',1,1155,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',0) - 1155 variables.
How to use the loop in here?

Answer (score 2):

Use pointwise vector operations:

```
% given A,B,C,D,E
A = rand(1,1155);
B = rand(1,1155);
C = rand(1,1155);
D = rand(1,1155);
E = rand(1,1155);
% compute F
F = (A+B)./(C + D.*E);
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what i meant